# nodejs selenium add a function to webdriver (highlight element) click() is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, overriding

trying to create a new function in chromedriver or override existing findelement() function

First steps for me was create new instead of override to test it

```
 const driver = await new Builder()
  .forBrowser("chrome")
  .setChromeOptions(
      new chrome.Options()
          .windowSize(screen)
          )
  .build();
  driver.findElementWithHighlight = async (locator) => {
    let element = await driver.findElement(locator);
    await driver.executeScript("arguments[0].style.border='3px solid red'", element);
    return driver.findElement(locator);
  };
```

then in another function I call

```
await driver.findElementWithHighlight(some locator).click();
```

but after all this I get this error:

**TypeError: driver.findElementWithHighlight(...).click is not a function**

What do I do wrong here?
Why my new function do not have click() method if it returns same WebElementPromise?

Answer (score 1):

It returns a promise and you are calling the `.click()` on the Promise object. Instead wrap it around `(await driver.findElementWithHighlight(...)).click()`. So It will be awaited and you will be able to call your click function.

Comment: ok that works now, but maybe there is something i can do to leave 
await driver.findElementWithHighlight(some locator).click(); as is? 
maybe in function definition?

Comment: No, but you can 

`driver.findElementWithHighlight(some locator).then(element => {
    element.click()
})`

Answer (score 0):

You can keep making more functions

```
driver.findElementWithHighlight = async (locator) => {
    let element = await driver.findElement(locator);
    await driver.executeScript("arguments[0].style.border='3px solid red'", element);
    return driver.findElement(locator);
};
driver.findElementWithHighlightAndClick = async (locator) => {
    return driver.findElementWithHighlight(locator)
        .then((highlighted) => {
            return highlighted.click();
        });
};

driver.findElementWithHighlightAndClick(some_locator);
```